# Are there any effective treatments for Armillaria root diseas (AKA shoestring root rot)?

Tags: trees, diseases, fungus

A client recently lost a maple to a suspected case of Armillaria root disease. She is reporting that a nearby sycamore is showing signs of the same disease. We would ordinarily remove the tree and roots and burn everything, but due to the location and maturity of the tree, she is willing to try anything to save it - even non-organic options.

Comment: Google has some solution, but I never experienced such products so I cannot recommend it. I think it will be a long and difficult treatment: soil is probably full of spores, so the plant should be treated for long time. Removing top part of soils seems sensible (it is also a standard cure before planting new trees: Armillaria doesn't like air), but I think *she* will go deeper.  Note: a photo could also help, maybe it is too late (wood already rotten).

Comment: 'Suspected' case isn't good enough.  You need a REAL test or a Master Gardner, Arborist to tell you a FOR SURE.  Please, a picture would be necessary, twigs of the tree between healthy and unhealthy, sliced on the diagonal, other twigs with the cut just below the bark.  Also, any other mysterious cases of trees, shrubs dying in the vicinity possibly 'up'  stream?  Did she take any pictures of the maple before removing it?  I would go to the nearest cooperative extension service for soil tests, Arborists and find out FOR SURE what is happening

Comment: Don't worry Stormy. It'll be diagnosed by someone qualified to do so and to apply any curative agents (if there are any.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming (1) that the signs are indeed of Armillaria root disease (ie the Q to be answered is as the Title) and (2) *effective treatment* here means of some beneficial impact (without necessarily achieving a complete cure) then according to [Forest Insect & Disease Leaflet 78](https://www.na.fs.fed.us/spfo/pubs/fidls/armillaria/armillaria.htm) by R.E. Williams, C.G. Shaw, III, P.M. Wargo, and W.H. Sites:

> chemical fumigants, including chloropicrin, methyl bromide, and carbon disulfide, can reduce the infection level.

In general however practical advice is to prefer reducing the stress on infected or at risk trees, for example by dealing with other pests.